# Issue in create layout in ionic 2

Tags: tabs, ionic2

i created two tabs one is login and other one is enquiry. Login tab work properly . when i created enquiry layout i got error that is below. I am beginner for ionic 2 so if any one have tutorial please share with me.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm">
browser_adapter.js:77 Error: Uncaught (in promise): ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm">
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at zone.js:574
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:256)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:474)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:426)

zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm"> ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm">", stack: "Error: ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one…//localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:55701:22)"}consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm">(…)consoleError @ zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
4livereload.js?snipver=1:74 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:35729/livereload' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Used Code

enquiry.html

```
<ion-content>
       <p *ngIf="submitAttempt" style="color: #ea6153;">Please fill out all details accurately.</p>

        <ion-list no-lines>

            <form [ngFormModel]="slideOneForm">

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
                    <ion-input #firstName (change)="elementChanged(firstName)" ngControl="firstName" type="text" [class.invalid]="!slideOneForm.controls.firstName.valid && (firstNameChanged || submitAttempt)"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item *ngIf="!slideOneForm.controls.firstName.valid  && (firstNameChanged || submitAttempt)">
                    <p>Please enter a valid name.</p>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Last Name</ion-label>
                    <ion-input #lastName (change)="elementChanged(lastName)" ngControl="lastName" type="text" [class.invalid]="!slideOneForm.controls.lastName.valid && (lastNameChanged || submitAttempt)"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item *ngIf="!slideOneForm.controls.lastName.valid  && (lastNameChanged || submitAttempt)">
                    <p>Please enter a valid name.</p>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label floating>Age</ion-label>
                    <ion-input #age (change)="elementChanged(age)" ngControl="age" type="number" [class.invalid]="!slideOneForm.controls.age.valid && (ageChanged || submitAttempt)"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>

                <ion-item *ngIf="!slideOneForm.controls.age.valid  && (ageChanged || submitAttempt)">
                    <p>Please enter a valid age.</p>
                </ion-item>
            </form>
        </ion-list>
        <button primary (click)="save()">Create Account!</button>
</ion-content>
```

enquiry.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/enquiry/enquiry.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

    export class EnquiryPage {

      public items;
      slideOneForm: ControlGroup;

      firstNameChanged: boolean = false;
      lastNameChanged: boolean = false;
      ageChanged: boolean = false;

      submitAttempt: boolean = false;

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

          this.slideOneForm = formBuilder.group({
          firstName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
          lastName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
          age: ['', AgeValidator.isValid]
          });
      }

        this.items = [
            {title: 'item1',id: '1'},
            {title: 'item2',id: '2'},
            {title: 'item3',id: '3'},
            {title: 'item4',id: '4'},
            {title: 'item5',id: '5'},
            {title: 'item6',id: '6'}
        ];

        onChange(selectedItem) {
            console.log('Selected item: '+selectedItem);
        }
        elementChanged(input){
          let field = input.inputControl.name;
          this[field + "Changed"] = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be using form classes but it doesn't look like you've imported them. Have you got this in your page? `import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators, Control} from '@angular/common';`

Comment: yes this is the problem...thanx Will Harris

Answer (score 0):

Where does your form start and end ? and your submit button should be within the form

The issue here is your trying to merge your form with your tabs `slideOneForm: ControlGroup;` which is not right.

```
<form #RegisterForm="ngForm" novalidate>


<button (click)="save(RegisterForm)" type="submit" primary block>Login</button>

</form>
```

Comment: this same coding i do for my first tab (login tab) it will work fine

Comment: @Varshilshah but it's complaining about "myCoolForm" is that the login  form name ?

Comment: @LeRoy `myCoolForm` is just an example provided by the error message